# jooQ TableRecord .insert() with Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I am working with jooQ (MySQL). So I want to use `insert` statement

My code is here

```
 MixedRecord mixedRecord = dslContext.newRecord(Tables.MIXED);
 mixedRecord.setName("A");
 mixedRecord.setDescription("B");
 mixedRecord.insert();
```

After Execution this fragment `mixedRecord.getId()` is `null`

DB config is here

```
<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration" name="config">
        <property name="SQLDialect">
            <value type="org.jooq.SQLDialect">MYSQL</value>
        </property>
        <property name="connectionProvider" ref="connectionProvider"/>
</bean>
```

sql script of `mixed` table is here

```
CREATE TABLE `mixed` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=13386 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Does anyone have an idea why `mixedRecord.getId()` is `null`?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it's MyISAM related. jOOQ integration tests only work with InnoDB. Can you confirm that this issue disappears if you switch the engine to InnoDB?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue with no success. Created issue [#5789](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5789) on GitHub to track this